# VBA delete entire row with number (variable of For loop)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm struggling with a very basic issue:

```
Public Sub Optionfilter()
'Dim c As Range
Dim StrikeD As Date
Dim RefD As Date
Dim StrikeP As Integer
Dim S As Range
Dim R As Range
Dim XVAR As Integer
Dim Intervall As String
Dim Number As Integer
Dim TotalRow As Integer
Dim L As Integer
For Each S In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("J6:J" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").UsedRange.Cells(S.Row, S.Column + 1).Value > XVAR Then
        Debug.Print S.Row
        L = S.Row
        **ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Rows(L).Delete
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Rows("S.Row").Delete
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range(S, 1).EntireRow.Delete**
else
end if
next S
end sub
```

I just want to delete the entire row with with the number coming for the loop (s.row) depending on the upper condition and everything works fine besides the actuall deleting of this row

Comment: Just use a filter here. And use `Long` instead of `Integer`.

Comment: `S` is already a range (a cell) so `S.EntireRow.Delete` will work fine. As will `If S.Value > XVAR Then` In fact the entire loop's body could just be `If S.Value > XVAR Then S.EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: You put `S.Row` in quotes which is invalid. You should not use `L` and `S` to represent the same thing since it is causing you some confusion. If you want to access the row just use `Rows(S.Row)` although I prefer `Range("J" & S.Row).EntireRow.Delete`. However, you should still use @BigBen suggestion as it's minimal steps to accomplish this

Comment: When deleting rows you typically want to work from the bottom to the top.

Comment: Hello Guys, thank you very much for the responses, but on everything, I tried I get the same error "Run-time error 1004" Application defined or subject defined error"

Comment: Regarding the filter I don't think its going to work since i will execute further operations on the residual data and therefore need the sheet "clean". If it makes sense

Comment: I amended the code a bit and posted it completly in here --> new question. Thank you guys: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60641502/vba-deleting-every-time-1-row-when-condition-not-fulfilled-with-variable-coordin

Comment: thank you very much for the elaboration and the time you took for it. I really appreciate it, thank you. It makes all sense, but after copying your code ( S.EntireRow.Delete) into my syntax I receive always the same error stated here: https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-0ea61a60a22c8fbbbf3e95c1b463b242