# VBA deleting every time 1 Row when condition not fulfilled with variable coordinates from FOR Loop

Tags: excel, vba

thank you all in advance for your help. I'm not an advanced coder at all but in some way managed to make to following code work, except one really basic thing.I'm struggling with a very basic issue namely the actual deleting of 1 row every time the condition is not getting fulfilled. And the number of the row should be taken from a FOR loop. The coordinate in which the FOR loop is currently positioned should be reflected by S.Row but as I showed below, I've been trying multiple ways of deleting it and I get always an error with "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" It's driving me crazy, please help. ONE MORE TIME THANK YOU ALL:

```
   Public Sub Optionfilter()
Dim StrikeD As Date
Dim RefD As Date
Dim StrikeP As Integer
Dim S As Range
Dim R As Range
Dim XVAR As Integer
Dim Intervall As String
Dim Number As Integer
Dim TotalRow As Integer
Dim L As Integer

XVAR = 5
Intervall = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("I2").Value
                    Debug.Print Intervall
Number = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("G2").Value
                    Debug.Print Number
                    Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("G2").Address
                    Debug.Print "-----------------------------------------"

XP:

For Each S In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("J6:J" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)
                    Debug.Print S.Address & " in the Calc Loop"
                    Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").UsedRange.Cells(S.Row, S.Column - 1).Value
                    Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").UsedRange.Cells(S.Row, S.Column - 1).Address
        StrikeD = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").UsedRange.Cells(S.Row, S.Column - 1).Value
                    Debug.Print StrikeD
                    Debug.Print "-----------------------------------------"

        RefD = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("E2").Value
                    Debug.Print RefD
        RefD = DateAdd(Intervall, Number, RefD)
                    Debug.Print RefD
        DIFFRAW = Abs(StrikeD - RefD)
                    Debug.Print DIFFRAW

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").UsedRange.Cells(S.Row, S.Column + 1).Value = DIFFRAW

        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").UsedRange.Cells(S.Row, S.Column + 1).Value > XVAR Then
            Debug.Print S.Row
            L = S.Row
            'This code below is not deleting anything for some reason it's just getting executed but no row disappear/delete
            Rows(S.Row).EntireRow.Delete
            'This code below is also not deleting anything for some reason it's just getting executed but no row disappear/delete
            Range("J" & S.Row).EntireRow.Delete
            'This code below is giving me the mentioned ERROR
            'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Rows(L).Delete
            'OR Run-time error 438
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").S.EntireRow.Delete
            'OR
            Range("A" & S.Row).EntireRow.Delete
            'OR
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Rows("S.Row").Delete
            'OR
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range(S, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        Else
        End If

Next S

TotalRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                    Debug.Print TotalRow
                    Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").UsedRange.Cells(S.Row, S.Column).Address
                    Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").UsedRange.Cells(S.Row, S.Column).Value

Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets("Data") 'After we deleted the old datasheet, we now insert a new (empty) one
Sheets(3).Name = "TEMP" 'and rename it instead of the defaultname to

If TotalRow <= 10 Then ' And ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").UsedRange.Cells(S.Row, S.Column).Value > 0 Then
For Each R In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("J6:J" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").UsedRange.Cells(S.Row).Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Temp").Cells(j, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    j = j + 1 'This is a controlvariabel to write the copied cell everytime in a new row
 Next R
Else
XVAR = XVAR - 1
GoTo XP

End If
End Sub




'S eine erste Position zu ordnen
'zusätzlichen Goto einfpügen falls 0 resultate sind und schleife mit Prioritisierung der ergebnisse -->besser davor als danahc usw.

'       Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Cells(S.Row, S.Column + 7).Value

        's.Value = Replace(s.Value, ",", "") 'delete the ","
'        If InStr(1, S, "S") > 0 Then 'The command InStr(1, s, "S") respond the place (position) where it found "S" in the cellstring
'        '(s), for example: 1/5/3... basically it looks if in this cell the letter appears
'                  S.Value = Replace(S.Value, " ", "") 'If it has found an "S" in the cell value (for example in the portgolionumber
'                  '011 1044 S02) then it replaces all " " by "" and write the new value (0111044S02) in the cell
'        End If 'Ends the if condition
```

Comment: Have you tried implementing the suggestions made in the comments to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60638340/vba-delete-entire-row-with-number-variable-of-for-loop)?

Comment: Note that you really shouldn't delete inside a loop.

Comment: Also please try using a variable to refer to your worksheet - better to write `ws` 100 times than `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")` and so much easier to read.

Comment: Hello @BigBen yes I tried to redefine L to Long it didn't change anything It all results in the upper mentioned error message. The Filter function won't work because I really want to delete these rows and have afterwards only the "good" results. Besides that, I want to execute further operation on it as you can see. Maybe you could elaborate why deleting is not good? Just to give you an explanation I'm having around 13000 rows therefore I want to delete in the beginning the max amount not to waste ressources of the pc later and therefore enhance it. Thank you very much Big Ben

Comment: What about [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60638340/vba-delete-entire-row-with-number-variable-of-for-loop#comment107280552_60638340) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60638340/vba-delete-entire-row-with-number-variable-of-for-loop#comment107282518_60638340)? You're not trying either of those suggestions as far as I can see.

Comment: You can delete the visible rows after filtering. This avoids having to loop.

Comment: I've tried them and it didn't succeed therefore I replaced it by the original code. Believe me BigBen I'm trying everything because its very urgent. And I won't repost and answer if it would be already resolved. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with how you tried those suggestions in particular, because they are good.

Comment: @BigBen done please see above. Just to clarify: The code above is the entire code in case there should be something defined and sth is missing. And regarding the comments maybe I executed the improvement wrong. The Lower DELETE part is containing multiple tries to delete it if I don't have to use L and cann just reference S that would be awesome. It's jsut doesn't work for some reason

Answer (score 1):

I can't follow what you posted here but this addresses the core of your original question:

```
Dim i As Long, ws As Worksheet, XVAR As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
'XVAR = '...something

For i = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row To 6 Step -1
    If ws.Cells(i, 11).Value > XVAR Then
        ws.Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be related to the issue you are having, but I'm writing as an answer to help with misunderstandings it looks like you are having.

Your variable `S` is a range. As such excel knows everything about that range when you set it. It knows it's value, it's row and column, the sheet in which it's contained, and the workbook in which that sheet is contained. All of your code where you qualify your `S` variable or pulling the row only to use it's `Long` value to refer to the same row... is superfluous at best and causing errors at worse.

For instance:

```
Rows(S.Row).EntireRow.Delete
```

You are literally saying "Grab the number representing the row in which this cell resides and in whatever worksheet is currently active (who knows what that is...?), delete the entire row that corrsponds to that number".

Instead:

```
S.EntireRow.Delete
```

Now it says "Delete the entire row in which the cell held in variable `S` resides".

---

As for your error:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").S.EntireRow.Delete
```

This says "The cell in variable `S`, for which we already know which sheet and workbook it resides by the nature of the range object being held in this variable, (let me tell you regardless though) that's specifically in ThisWorkbook and the Worksheet called `Data` delete it's entire row."

Excel isn't down with this because you can't qualify a range object like this with a worksheet and workbook. It's already set and unchangeable. Range `S` is already 100% unchange-ably in Sheet "Data" and `ThisWorkbook`. Your attempt to tell excel this information again is just making excel angry.

Instead:

```
 S.EntireRow.Delete
```

Which looks familiar.

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for the elaboration and the time you took for it. I really appreciate it, thank you. It makes all sense, but after copying your code ( S.EntireRow.Delete) into my syntax I receive always the same error stated here: https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-0ea61a60a22c8fbbbf3e95c1b463b242